# High DPI scaling in Windows 10, 8, 8.1, and 7?

Tags: winforms, dpi, multiplatform, .net-4.7, dpi-aware

Which is the simplest way to make my application DPI-aware for Windows 10 Creator's edition, Windows 7, 8, and 8.1? I see a lot of different options to add to the `app.config` and `app.manifest` and am just confused on which to add for my case.  Was high-dpi even supported before Windows 10 Creator's Update??
I am developing Winforms using Visual Studio 2017 and we can not move to WPF. I have read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) article but am still confused.

I'm thinking of adding

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.comn:compatibility.v1">
  <application>
    <!-- Windows 10 compatibility -->
    <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
  </application>
</compatibility>
```

to the manifest and

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
  <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

to the app.config for the Windows 10 but then I need it to fall back for Windows 8, 8.1 and 7.

Comment: what version of .net are you using?

Comment: windows 10 has a lot more features than 7, 8 and 8.1 had so it won't be perfect on those other systems.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.7 framework

Comment: DPI virtualization has been around for 12 years, first introduced at Vista.  Being able to change the monitor DPI goes back much further, it was already pretty common to use 125% in XP.  But programs did not handle it well, thus the virtualization feature.  It got an extra boost a Win10 because now the OS installer no longer picks 100%.  What you do with the manifest is disable the virtualization, you promise that your program knows how to scale properly.  Just a promise, nothing more.  Actually *making* it scale properly is however still a stretch for many programmers.

Comment: Okay so the OS does all of the scaling on OSes prior to Windows 10, without allowing the application to do any scaling? So all this high-dpi / dpi-aware .NET stuff (even the "legacy" way in the manifest) is just for Windows 10 (I think Creators Update)?

Comment: No, as noted dealing with DPI has been useful for two decades already.  But certainly ignored for two decades.  The only thing that is new about it is that the Win10 installer no longer picks 100% as the default setting (users never changed it) and that 4K monitors became very affordable.  So not dealing with it gets a lot more noticeable, the virtualization feature produces notably fuzzy text.  The way VS works makes it very noticeable as well, it is a dpiAware app and if your program is not then the design view can look very different from the runtime view.